# lsof gives warning for some daemon

Tags: linux, lsof, fuse

lsof | grep /var is giving me following error

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/user/.gvfs
  Output information may be incomplete.
```

what can be possible reason for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a virtual filesystem, used by gnome. It doesn't implement everything `stat()` wants to get so it returns an error. Here is a quote from Fedora mailing list about a similar problem:

> The issue is that when the user is
>   logged in, fuse creates a memory
>   resident filesystem interpreted by the
>   user process.
>
> This user process doesn't implement
>   anything but owner. All else is
>   refused. Root can't access it because
>   it isn't the owner, and can't override
>   that because the fuse filesystem
>   doesn't implement/support the
>   override.

Comment: I got your point. I see such type of warnings come in rsync etc also.